cannot parse csv file start with unexpected character
I'm tring to parse a csv file, but it's head start with character ZWNBSP which make my code fail, how can i parse this csv as expected?
csv content
ZWNBSP"AccountId","AccountNumber","AccountName","CustomerId","CustomerName","CurrencyCode","Spend","Impressions","Clicks","Installs","VideoViews","Conversions","Sales","TimePeriod"

code trial
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)


func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("/Desktop/193657270154964993.csv")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    reader := csv.NewReader(file)
    for {
        record, err := reader.ReadAll()
        if err != nil {
            break 
        }

        fmt.Println(record)
    }
}


error info
bare " in non-quoted-field



@jiaJimmy: "character ZWNBSP" is actually a Byte Order Mark (BOM): Unicode FAQ: BOM and Wikipedia: Byte order mark

@rocka2q As the csv file start with ZWNBSP， how can I parse the file correctly

@jiaJimmy: If the file has a BOM then discard it. For example, https://go.dev/play/p/DviwFJE_7UQ.

@rocka2q Thank you for your suggestion. I added the additional judgment of the existence of utf8BOM.

This github page on the subject explains why encoding/csv does not take a BOM into account (the specification it is based on does not mention it): https://github.com/golang/go/issues/33887 . There are also examples in the comments on how to resolve it yourself, although the example code that rocka2q provided seems perfectly fine and does not require installing yet another package to do one task only.

I recommend using the Golang's own x/text package: it has a Transformer type and BOM-aware encodings that can handle removing (and inserting) a BOM with just one extra line of code.
I created this small sample CSV which has a UTF-8BOM:
A,B
1,x
2,y
3,z

If I run this small program:
func main() {
    var r io.Reader

    r, _ = os.Open("input.csv")

    csvr := csv.NewReader(r)
    records, _ := csvr.ReadAll()
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", records)
}

it prints, with the BOM before "A":
[["\ufeffA" "B"] ["1" "x"] ["2" "y"] ["3" "z"]]

If I modify that program and a add a Transformer which specifically decodes UTF-8BOM encoded bytes (to just UTF-8):
import (
    ...
    "golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode"
    "golang.org/x/text/transform"
)

func main() {
    var r io.Reader

    r, _ = os.Open("input.csv")
    r = transform.NewReader(r, unicode.UTF8BOM.NewDecoder())

    csvr := csv.NewReader(r)
    records, _ := csvr.ReadAll()
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", records)
}

it prints:
[["A" "B"] ["1" "x"] ["2" "y"] ["3" "z"]]

I chose to generically declare r as io.Reader so I could use the same variable and take that transformer-line in and out, for a compact example.  You could also write something more explicit and idiomatic, like:
fIn, _ := os.Open("input.csv")
defer fIn.Close()
bomDecoder := transform.NewReader(fIn, unicode.UTF8BOM.NewDecoder())
csvReader := csv.NewReader(bomDecoder)

If you need to re-encode with a BOM when you're done processing the CSV, create a writer with a BOM encoder:
fOut, _ := os.Create("output.csv")
defer fOut.Close()

t := transform.NewWriter(fOut, unicode.UTF8BOM.NewEncoder())

csvw := csv.NewWriter(t)
csvw.WriteAll(records)

% hexdump -C output.csv
00000000  ef bb bf 41 2c 42 0a 31  2c 78 0a 32 2c 79 0a 33  |...A,B.1,x.2,y.3|
00000010  2c 7a 0a                                          |,z.|
00000013

